# Multiple data attributes to array with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, google-maps

I am trying to produce a simple a array of map coordinates to pass to Google Maps.
I am currently retrieving the coords from the 'data-lat' and the 'data-lng' attributes of the element.

My code is as follows:

```
var dataList = cell.map(function() {
   return $(this).data("lat");
}).get();

dataList.join(',');

var dataList2 = cell.map(function() {
   return $(this).data("lng");
}).get();

dataList2.join(',');

var lats = $.merge(dataList.dataList2);
console.log(dataList[0],dataList2[0]);
```

I am not getting them to return in pairs that I can use as map coords
and I am sure my code smells bad.

I am just passing the coords to a standard Google.map.marker location.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try just `$(this).data()`, it will produce an object `{lng: 42, lat: 10}` (provided you don't have any other `data-`)

Comment: `return [ $(this).data("lat"), $(this).data("lng") ]`

Comment: Perfect...Thanks, I knew I was making it to complicated

Comment: So I ask a question on the question asking site, and get down voted...interesting. To think I did not try other options first is presumptuous at best. I was simply asking if there was a more concise manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, you are trying to do this :

```
var dataList = cell.map(function() {
    return [
        $(this).data("lat"),
        $(this).data("lng")
    ];
}).get();
console.log(dataList[0],dataList[1]);
// or
console.dir(dataList);
// or similar
```